# What does "iterable[, key]" mean in a method signature?

Tags: python

What is the structure of the second argument in `heapq.nlargest(n, iterable[, key])`?

As a Python rookie, I am only used to functions in the form myfunc(x, y, x). The `iterable[, key]` is confusing me!

Comment: It just means you have to provide the `n` argument, you have to provide the `iterable` argument, and the `key` argument is optional. It's not the syntax of calling the function, just the way of demonstrating the arguments in documentation

Comment: It's a documentation convention. `key` is optional, that's all.

Comment: Thanks! But why have I seen calls to this function such as "data = heapq.nlargest(2, enumerate(my_list), key=lambda x:x[1])", where the third argument has a "key=" to indicate which argument it is talking about? Surely the third argument in the provided list matches to the third argument in the function definition, by default?

Comment: It would work without the `key=`, but using `key=` has two benefits. First, it is easier for the reader of the code to know what it's for. Second, the person writing the code doesn't have to remember how many infrequently-used options with default values there are.

Answer (score 3):

They are separate arguments. `iterable` is the second argument; `key` is the optional third argument.